# What will happen to enable External marketing in Google play console?

Tags: android, google-play-console, google-play-console-beta

**External marketing**
Turn off external marketing if you don’t want your app to be advertised outside of Google Play

[image]

Is free?
Is there any benefit to enable this?

Comment: Did you discovered its real purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You can uncheck the "External marketing” to restrict the promotion of your app across Google-owned properties.

You can see more information here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9866151?hl=en

Comment: Your link is useless. It says no more than the little wrote on the Play Console. What does it really do?